# What happens when assigning unsigned integer to an signed integer of a lower width?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer, c++14, truncation

```
uint64_t one = 0x8000000000000002;
int32_t two = one;
```

Does this behaviour without a cast is warranted on all systems even little and big endian ones ?

If not what happens to the sign bit ? Does `two` can become a positive integer ?

Comment: You realize `one` is a positive number, yes?

Comment: @JohnKugelman fixed.